# flash[:notice] is shown on browser back again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, notice

Hej, 
i have a problem:
I'm using flash[:notice] in my rails app. 
A User comes to the page and creates a new object. The flash-message says "Created." Now he clicks on a link on the page. If he is coming back by using the "back" button of his browser the flash massage is presented again. 
flash.now[:notice] doesnt work either (i think and i tested). The problem is that there is no new rendering of the file.

Do you have any idea to prevent that? Thanks!

Comment: As you stated yourself, the problem isn't really related to flash[:notice], but rather the browers' behaviour to show the cached result. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the flash variable, but the browser caching.  This solution worked well for me using Rails 3.2 (from this thread [How to prevent browser page caching in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails)):

in application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :set_cache_buster

  def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I generally used following

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  <% flash[:notice]=nil %>
<% end %>
```

you can also use [discard](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash/FlashHash.html#M000312) method

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  <% flash.discard(:notice) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the cache to no-cache, no-store will result in unnecessary requests to your server. Instead you can use browser's localStorage / sessionStorage to achieve the desired effect.

I have written a detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921476/6590834

Answer (score 0):

I know the discard method, the problem is not the functionality of flash[:notice], the problem is that the browser isn't rendering the file again... 
I Think i have to fix it by using javascript...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails .