# Prevent users from displaying previously visited pages without clearing cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to prevent users from visiting previously visited pages after logout without clearing cache in rails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent the back action after logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263767/prevent-the-back-action-after-logout)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4265575/525478

Answer (score -1):

Are you using any gems like `devise` ? Simple to use and easy to set up. All is in the doc. We can't help you out without any further information like the gems you're using, what did you tried, ect. But in any case `devise` have what you're looking for.

Erasing caches still needs the approbation of the user by the way, but you can do it with Jquery : look here : https://api.jquery.com/removeData/

Comment: I have not used any gems. I just checked with session and it works fine but the problem is that after logout when user hits back button it displays the previous pages. Clearing the cache will affect performance so I am looking for any better solution. Thanks!

Comment: And in any case erasing cache needs the approbation of the user

Comment: You can still do it with a jquery script

Comment: I think clearing cache will not be the great as every time browser will load assets I will try using devise and will let you know

Comment: Using jquery? Can you please explain it.I means how we can achieve this using jquery

Comment: It's simple : you parse a wrapper containing all the content you want into a `.data()` in your script, then you call a `.removeData()` when the user click on the log-out button. Look here for more details: https://api.jquery.com/removeData/

Comment: But it's a bad solution to destroy the caches. The better way is to forbid an non connected user to see the content