# Why are Rails Authenticity Tokens session persistent and not unique to each submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, web2py, authenticity-token

I'm wondering why Rails form Authenticity Tokens last the entire session instead of being generated uniquely per each submission.

I'm coming from [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#Hidden-fields), where forms are generated with unique one-time tokens called `_formkey`. The formkey automatically prevents duplicate submissions resulting from double-clicking, back-button caching, etc.

In Rails, you apparently have to deal with the double-submission problem yourself (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4683161/165673). It seems to me that one-time Authenticity Tokens would solve this problem, as well as being more secure?

Comment: In particular, I think the one-time token approach is more secure against the [BREACH attack](http://breachattack.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One token for entire session is easier to implement. Think about a case where you have two opened tabs with forms.

One token for session is as secure as one-time token solution. At least as the protection against CSRF attacks.

> In Rails, you apparently have to deal with the double-submission problem yourself

There is out of the box solution for that. Read about `disable_with` option. Of course all  requests that modify data should be sent via HTTP POST, not GET.

Comment: @Igowan - Dunno if the easier to implement argument flies. web2py does it, and can easily handle multiple forms per page / across tabs (unique tokens actually make this easier i think). Regarding `disable_with`, that's a client-side solution- handy for ux but not a reliable way to prevent double submissions the way a tokenized-solution would.

Comment: @Yarin I use `disable_with` for many years and it works great. I don't understand what your problem really is.

Comment: @Igowin- `disable_with` won't help you with ajax form submissions that get triggered programmatically, or with cached forms that get re-hit after pressing the back button. If the integrity of your data is at stake you can't rely on view-based enforcement.

Comment: @Yarin In Rails data integrity is secured by the models layer. You can do this also using db constraints and checks. `disable_with` should be used to protect against double-submission problem - when someone accidentally double clicks submit button.

Comment: @Igowin - "In Rails data integrity is secured by the models layer" - You're right, good point. I may have been hung up on an imaginary problem..