# How to show the flash message in Rails only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to show the flash message in rails only once? I mean, when I delete something the flash says "Deleted (undo)", and then if I click a click and then the browser's Back button the message is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a generic browser caching problem.
You can force your browser to reload a page while hitting the back button by setting some no-cache headers.

You could try this approach: (found after a quick google search, you might want to dig deeper)

http://blog.serendeputy.com/posts/how-to-prevent-browsers-from-caching-a-page-in-rails/

Comment: lol, after I submitted this answer I saw you actually ended up with the same post some seconds ago.

Answer (score 17):

You could use

```
flash.now
```

Here's a thumb-rule.

```
In your controller, use flash when you're redirecting and flash.now when rendering.
```

Comment: In the particular case I'm redirecting - from the Show view to the Index. My question is whether the flash message can be removed after you leave the page that has the flash message and then you click the Back button.

Comment: I found in this stackoverflow thread that this is related to caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails