# Ruby on Rails return a message to the user after invalid login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new at ruby on rails and I am trying to set up a simple log in for a part of the site. I have gotten the log in to work however when the user puts in a incorrect username, I want a message to say "Invalid log in. Try again."  I can not figure this out any help would be greatly appreciated

HERE IS MY CODE IN MY CONTROLLER

```
class SimpleloginController < ApplicationController  
  def namein    

  end

  def transmain  
    @familyname_out = params[:family_name_in] #textbox name from the input file 
    name_out  = params[:family_name_in]   
    if found = Family.find_by_name(name_out)   
      redirect_to manin_manout_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully" 
    else  
      redirect_to simplelogin_namein_path, :notice => "Invalid login. Try again" 
    end    
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def transmain   
  unless Family.find_by_name(params[:family_name_in]).blank?
    redirect_to manin_manout_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully" 
  else  
    redirect_to simplelogin_namein_path, :notice => "Invalid login. Try again" 
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you rendering the notice messages in your view?

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= msg %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank your for help this is close, when I type in the wrong username it says invalid user name which is what I want however, when I first go to the page it says invalid log in please try again before I put in a username

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142527/how-to-show-the-flash-message-in-rails-only-once This is assuming that you hit the Back button or backspace on your browser

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the behavior you're experiencing, but I think this line

```
if found = Family.find_by_name(name_out)
```

will return a RecordNotFound error if name_out doesn't exist in the db.

For a good look at authentication with rails check out Ryan Bates' Railcast [Authentication from Scratch (Revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised)