# how to disable site content from history for unauthenticated user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, browser-history

I'm bothered by following case.

I have user logged in, he is able to see some data of his. When he logs out then another one can come and go back in browser history to see his data, suggested links etc. 
Does anyone know how to disallow this?

Does https help to solve this issue?

I'm using rails 3.1 so anyone got similiar issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails), this [page](http://blog.serendeputy.com/posts/how-to-prevent-browsers-from-caching-a-page-in-rails/) and another recent [page](http://blog.developerjeff.com/2011/04/01/rails-prevent-browser-page-caching/). [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)'s a rails guide about caching. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9