# How to get Signin page on clicking Browser's "Back" button after a sign-out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser

I am following Michael Hartl's Tutorial.

When a user signs in, then signs out and clicks on browser's back button, then the user's home page is displayed, which I don't want. I want the user to get the sign in page when he clicks on browser's "Back" button and not the homepage after a sign-out.

Thanx! :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically your browser is caching the the web pages, and rails is currently configured to allow you to do that. You will have to manually specify in rails that you do not want page caching to occur.

Refer to this [link here.](http://www.fordevs.com/2011/10/how-to-prevent-browser-from-caching-a-page-in-rails.html) It should be exactly what you are looking for.

Basically what the page I linked is telling you to do is to add a couple of lines to `application_controller.rb`:

This:

```
before_filter :set_no_cache
```

and the function:

```
def set_no_cache
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hey, I tried this code already. It's given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails I guess, I am doing something wrong coz it worked for everyone. Is there anything I need to do after adding this code in application_controller.rb?

Comment: This is how my application_controller.rb looks like            `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
   include SessionsHelper

  before_filter :set_cache_buster
  def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
end`

Comment: You forgot the line `before_filter :set_no_cache` in your before_filters. Add that and it should work.

Comment: Danish, it still doesn't work! I pasted the code you have given exactly. What else can I do? And thanx a zillion for trying to help me out. :)

Comment: Have you tried restarting your rails server? And no problem. Also, it may help to clear the cache of your web browser.

Comment: Ya, I restarted my server and now this is how my code looks like `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   protect_from_forgery
   include SessionsHelper
   before_filter :set_no_cache 
   def set_no_cache
     response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
     response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
     response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
   end
end`

Comment: That code looks fine. Are you sure the page is caching? Like if you reload the page after pressing the back button, does it still work or not? If the page still works even after a reload, then it's not a caching problem.

Comment: Danish, the page is getting reloaded after clicking "back" button also.

Answer (score -2):

simply redirect to sign in page on sign out button and disable browser back button.

Comment: Is it okay if I disable the "back" button. I mean, what action would "back" button then have on other pages?

Comment: This is neither practical not possible. First of all, you're [introducing a worst practice by breaking convention](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html) (the back button) for no real benefit to the user. Secondly, you're ignoring the fact that **all web commands are suggestions**. It is up to the browser whether to follow them. What if the user is using Lynx? Its 'back button' can't be disabled, can it?