# How to handle additional login after pressing back with Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm building an application in rails that uses devise for authentication. When you log in to the application it redirects you to home page. But if you then press back you are presented with the login form again. If you then log in to a new user account you again get redirected to the home page but are still logged in as the original user.

Instead I want an error to pop up on the second login saying that we were unable to log the user in to the second account because they were already logged in.

From my research it looks like I should be able to do this with a custom controller, is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually settled with (which didn't give me exactly the behavior I wanted is to disable caching on the login page. I got the pointer from this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/748646/175830

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, detect if there is already a signed in user on the login page. If there is, redirect to where they should go after the login. This prevents any logged in use from seeing the login page.

Comment: This works if the user is already logged in and then manually visit the login page. But if the user logs in and presses back. Then when you press back none of the controller methods get fired at all.