# Rails Caching a Page Improperly - How to Stop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very simple test case that explains the problem.

Here's the page that I'm displaying in Rails in an ERB file.

```
<div><%=rand%></div>

<p><a href="http://google.com">Go</a></p>
```

To show the error, I load the page.  I note the random number displayed as `rand1`.  I click on the Google link.  I click the browser's "Back" button.  I note the random number displayed as `rand2`.

Here's the problem:
In Firefox and Chrome, rand1 != rand2 (always).
In Safari and IE, rand1 == rand2 (always).

Why the discrepancy in browsers?  Why is Safari and IE caching the output from Rails while the other two browsers are not?  How do I get Safari and IE to refresh the page?

(This is a simple test case to show the problem - this has implications in my Backbone application).

Comment: What kind of caching are you using? Page, Action and Fragment caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebKit in particular has an aggressive page caching strategy for handling exactly the case you're describing (clicking a link and then immediately clicking the back button). The idea is to make the back action happen almost instantaneously by caching not just the resources but also the DOM and other state of the page. You can read about it in these two articles:

- [WebKit Page Cache I — The Basics](http://www.webkit.org/blog/427/webkit-page-cache-i-the-basics/)
- [WebKit Page Cache II — The `unload` Event](http://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/)

You may be able to use a combination of the `load`/`unload` and `pageshow`/`pagehide` events to accomplish what you need.

I'm not sure if IE implements something similar to WebKit, but maybe this will fix it too.

Answer (score 2):

IE and Safari appear to be caching the response from the server, obviously; as long as your browsers are configured correctly, you can change this by changing the Cache-Control header in the response.

[Another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails) shows the appropriate way to do that, though in Rails 3 there's a shortcut method to accomplish this: you can invoke [`expires_now`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet.html#method-i-expires_now) in the controller action to avoid manually setting all these headers.

Comment: No, that didn't seem to work.  Added the tag and still saw the same behavior.