# Devise redirect after login or logout doesn't work with Rails page caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, page-caching

I'm using Devise for authentication in my Rails app on Heroku.

I have redirects after login and logout setup the way it's suggested to do so in the Devise wiki. (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update)

application_controller.rb:

```
after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
  session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless (request.fullpath =~ /\/users\/sign_in/ || request.fullpath =~ /\/users\/sign_out/ || request.fullpath =~ /\/users\/sign_up/ || request.fullpath =~ /\/users\/edit/ || request.fullpath =~ /\/ajax_utilities/ || request.fullpath =~ /\/assets/)
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end
```

The redirects work fine until I enable page caching with code like this:

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController

  def index
      expires_in 1.minutes, public: true
  end

end
```

I'm 99% sure that store_location isn't ever being called because the way page caching works in Rails the application controller would never even be reached because Rack serves the static HTTP without touching Rails.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can take advantage of Rails page caching while also having my redirects after login/logout work correctly for Devise?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the page caching include specific user information?

Comment: Interesting problem, just curious why do you need the page caching code in the AboutController. Trying to follow your conceptual intention.

Comment: @Swards: the page caching does not include specific user info. I have some ajax that loads all user-specific content after the page is finished loading.

Comment: @bfont: in my testing with blitz.io (a load-testing that steadily hits your website with more and more traffic and tells you response times), page caching gives me the quickest response time, followed by fragment caching my views, followed by no caching at all. I'm page caching almost all of my site's pages, not just the about page, I just put the about controller code there as an example of the code I'm using for caching.

Answer (score 0):

Try a before filter in the `AboutController`

```
before_filter :destroy_cache

def destroy_cache
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

Not sure its exactly what you need but a starting point perhaps

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails) and the original [citation](http://blog.serendeputy.com/posts/how-to-prevent-browsers-from-caching-a-page-in-rails/)

Update:

Take a look at this [article](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/03/10/rails-redirect-previous-page-after-devise-sign-in/). It will show ou how to set up friendly forwarding which sounds like what you want to do

Comment: hmmmm. I don't think this is what I want. I'm hoping to have page caching enabled, not disable caching in the browser.

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this. Are you just trying to setup "friendly forwarding"?

Comment: Let's say the user is on my contact page. When they click the login link, they end up at a login page. After successful login, they should be redirected back to the page they were on before they clicked the login link, in this case the contact page. The same should be true for logout. Devise provides convenient drop-in code to do this, which is what I posted above in the application controller. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have been written with page caching in mind, because with page caching, only nginx responds to requests: Rails code isn't ever executed.

Comment: Ok now I understand a little better. That is called friendly forwarding. Its well documented like the link I added to my answer. However, you have to figure out how to include page caching. This is the problem

Comment: Yep. I'm not sure if there's a known solution for combining Devise login/logout redirects with Rails page caching or if I'm going to just have to settle for fragment caching for now. I'm pretty sure I can do my own forwarding with javascript and cookies but I think that opens up security vulnerabilities.