# After a succesful sign-in when user click on the back button of the browser, "login" page should not appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I have a log in page where user enters email and password and then the user is redirected to home page, but when i press the back button it takes me back to the log in page. How do i prevent that from happening in rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the LoginController (controller which is using for login)

```
 before_filter :set_cache_buster

  def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

This will clear the browser history

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails)