# How can I exempt images from Rails cache-busting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I've implemented this solution to help prevent browser page caching, based on the question [How to prevent browser page caching in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails):

```
def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

While this certainly work, it feels a bit like killing an ant with a sledgehammer; everything is prevent from caching, including images (e.g., a hamburger icon, or other small images like that). When navigating from page to page, this results in unsightly flashes of empty content while these images are reloaded.

Is there a way that I can prevent general caching, but exempt certain assets?

Comment: Are you trying to solve this problem in development, or production? If the latter, what kind of production environment is it? Heroku?

Comment: I'm seeing the issue in development, but hadn't thought to try running in production mode and seeing what happens. Will give that a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for miss on tags, but as i see nginx can be a perfect answer to it - just serve static content (images/css/etc) with nginx and pass all other requests to backend (ruby)