# Set headers in Padrino

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I am attempting to remove caching and discovered this post:

[How to prevent browser page caching in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails)

The problem it along with a number of other posts relating to ruby rails refer to an application_controller.rb file that my project does not have. I inherited this system so wasnt part of its initial development. Can someone explain why this would be the case? I am using padrino and in my config folder i have the following files:

- Deploy

  - production.rb
  - staging.rb
- Recipes

  - base.rb
  - nginx.rb
  - rbenv.rb
- apps.rb
- boot.rb

Comment: You're saying your app doesn't have a  file called application_controller.rb in the app/controllers/ folder ? If that's the case, do you have any controllers at all in the folder? If yes, do they inherit from something ? i.e: class XController < ApplicationController

Comment: @Alexandre Voyer I have an app.rb file in the app folder but outside controllers folder. It starts with class ProjectName < Padrino::Application

Answer (score 1):

From what you've provided me I can say that I'm quite certain the project is using the Padrino ruby framework and not rails :)

See: http://www.padrinorb.com/

Comment: If that is the case what is used instead of the application controller?

Comment: That I'm not quite sure, there are some guides available ( http://www.padrinorb.com/guides ) in which you could dig further to see what does what :)