# Axios ajax call returns sometimes html

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

In `Vue.js 2` I"m making an ajax call with axios. It's all working fine. However when I go one page further and then go back to the page where the ajax call is made, the ajax call suddenly returns html so no json objects.

What could be going on here? When I test the url in postman I receive json back as wel?

My back-end is made with laravel 5.5.

**Html response:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if IEMobile]><html class=\"no-js iemobile\" lang=\"nl\"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class=\"no-js ie6\" lang=\"nl\"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class=\"no-js ie7\" lang=\"nl\"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class=\"no-js ie8\" lang=\"nl\"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class=\"no-js ie9\" lang=\"nl\"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class=\"no-js\" lang=\"nl\"><!--<![endif]-->\n<head>\n\t<!-- Google Tag Manager -->\n<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':\n        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],\n        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=\n        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);\n    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-TP9MVZN');</script>\n<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->\n    <meta data-required=\"true\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>\n\n<title>Televisies </title>\n\n<meta d…", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
```

Vue.js code looks like this:

```
Axios.get(url, { params: params }).then((response) => {
           console.log(response);
});
```

In my app.js file I set the header like this:

```
Axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Thanks

Comment: Check network tab to see what's going on there.

Comment: You might be receiving an error in html format. Can you post the response body here?

Comment: Please see my update above.

Comment: share your controller code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the solution. Rails is caching the the page as to reduce the amount of requests on navigating back.

To disable this behavior, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/748646/2418828)