# How to mark the post as read when the user viewed the post using AJAX calls in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need to mark a post read/unread when the user views the post or it remains unviewed by the user. For this task I have used AJAX call. But When I view it in browser all the posts are marked as read once I click on view post button. Post controller:

```
def show
 @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
 @read_status = @post.Read_status_entry(current_user)
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :read_statuses
  has_many :users,through: :read_statuses

  def Read_status_entry(user)
    self.read_statuses.where(post_id: id, user_id: user.id).first_or_create
  end
end
```

Index page:

```html
<div class="container" >
  <% @posts.each do |post|%>
    <div class="well">
     <% if ReadStatus.where(" user_id = ? AND post_id = ?",current_user.id,post.id).blank? %>
       <p class="read_text" >Unread</p>
      <%end %>
      <h4><b><%= post.title  %> (<%= post.topic.topicname %>)</b></h4>
      <p><%= post.body %></p>
      <div>
        <%= image_tag post.image.url(:thumb) %>
      </div>
      <%= link_to "View Post", topic_post_path(topic_id:post.topic_id, id:post.id ), :class => 'btn btn-default btn1'%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

this is the view button where i need to do the ajax call when this button is clicked

```
<%= link_to "View Post", topic_post_path(topic_id:post.topic_id, id:post.id ), :class => 'btn btn-default btn1'%>
```

I have included the js code in application.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $(".read_text").hide();
  })
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent browser page caching in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711418/how-to-prevent-browser-page-caching-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is instead of doing `$(".read_text").hide();`
You should try and get the parent well element and use it to traverse to the appropriate child `.read_text` element.
`

```
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".read_text").css( "display", "none" );
})
```

`